# checking if a value in a data frame column exists in a list, and creating a new column acording to the checking result

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

**an example how i tried to solve it**

````
```
df = pd.DataFrame({'vals': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'ids': ['a', 'b', 'f', 'n','k'], 'ids2':['a','n','c', 'n','z'],'mylove': ['i', 'l', 'o', 'v','x'],'mysweet': ['e', 'n', 'a', 's','p'] })```

     vals    ids  ids2    mylove    mysweet
0     1       a    a        i          e
1     2       b    n        l          n
2     3       f    c        o          a
3     4       n    n        v          s
4     5       k    z        x          p
````

**will check each lists bellow**

```
``
AIMO,BIMO,CIMO,DIMO  = ['i'],['l'],['o'],['v','x']
aimo = df['mylove'].isin(AIMO)   #check if the value in the list is available in the column "mylove"
aimo1 = df[aimo]   #"because the above just gave me a boolean i created a new data frame" i dont know what to do"
aimo1.loc[:,'CATAGORY'] = 'CANDY'  # #"assigned this value to the new column called "CATAGORY""#mind this CATAGORY is a new column just created in this stage. ``
```

**then i repeated the above procedure**

```
``
bimo = df['mylove'].isin(BIMO)
bimo1 = df[bimo]
bimo1.loc[:,'CATAGORY'] = 'Goods'

cimo = df['mylove'].isin(CIMO)
cimo1 = df[cimo]
cimo1.loc[:,'CATAGORY'] = 'SERVICE'

dimo = df['mylove'].isin(DIMO)
dimo1 = df[dimo]
dimo1.loc[:,'CATAGORY'] = 'action'``
```

#**now i concatenate the columns and created a new dataframe**

````
```new_df = pd.concat([aimo1,bimo1,cimo1,dimo1])```
````

the result gate **new_df**

```
            vals    ids  ids2   mylove  mysweet CATAGORY
       0      1      a     a       i    e        CANDY
       1      2      b     n       l    n        Goods
       2      3      f     c       o    a        SERVICE
       3      4      n     n       v    s        action
       4      5      k     z       x    p        action
```

**i tried this one. but it tooks too long to get the result my original data. my original data has many rows. i am a new bee**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, I would use a dictionary to structure the mappings like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'vals': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'ids': ['a', 'b', 'f', 'n','k'], 'ids2':['a','n','c', 'n','z'],'mylove': ['i', 'l', 'o', 'v','x'],'mysweet': ['e', 'n', 'a', 's','p'] })

d = {'i':'Candy', 
     'l': 'Goods',
     'o': 'Service',
     'v': 'Action',
     'x': 'Action'}

df['Category'] = df['mylove'].map(d)

df
```

Output:

```
   vals ids ids2 mylove mysweet Category
0     1   a    a      i       e    Candy
1     2   b    n      l       n    Goods
2     3   f    c      o       a  Service
3     4   n    n      v       s   Action
4     5   k    z      x       p   Action
```

Comment: You are really a life saver. i was late to reply because i was searching a way to create a new dictionary. because the list has many values.